# Late 2010 macbook air, can't install os again

Tags: macbook-pro

I had wiped my 2010 macbook air and had tried to reinstall the os in recovery mode but the message "this item is temporarily unavailable" keeps popping up as I try to install os lion. Can anyone help me out ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a weird issue, your best bet is probably to download the "[OS X Recovery Disk Assistant](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1433?locale=en_US)" to reinstall OS Lion.

From [Apple's website](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1433?locale=en_US):

> "To create an external OS X Recovery, download the OS X Recovery Disk Assistant application. Insert an external drive, launch the OS X  Recovery Disk Assistant,  select the drive where you would like to install, and follow the on screen instructions.
>
> When the OS X Recovery Disk Assistant completes, the new partition will not be visible in the Finder or Disk Utility. To access OS X Recovery, reboot the computer while holding the Option key. Select Recovery HD from the Startup Manager. "

**Note:** In order to create an external OS X  Recovery using the OS X Recovery Assistant, your Mac must have an existing Recovery HD, which in your case it most likely already does.